# Continuous Scroll - Start Panning on end of contentSize for UIScrollView inside Pannable View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a structure something like below:

```
UIView
-----UITableView
```

means, a UITableView as a subview in a UIView. My UIView has UIPanGesture in Verticle directions.

On Scrolling UITableView it scrolls without any effect of Pan on its super view i.e. UIView. But when I reaches to end of ContentSize Table get bouncing effect as it usually have. But, I want to make superview Panneable when user reaches to end of scrolling so it will give an effect of continuous and smooth Scrolling..

By Using ,

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

It allows me to do Scroll and Pan simultaneously but in this case It don't allow me to work properly with UITableView. So I can't rely on this..

In Second try I tried to disable/enable Scroll enabled property of UITableView. but This way I got locked its scrolling so could not achieve Scrolling and Pan in single interaction.

**EDIT**

Please check the below example from Google maps app. It has similar continuous scroll & pan effect.

[image]